# How to have a transparent JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, transparent

This is my first post here, so I apologize if this is not the right way to ask. I would like suggestions to improve.

Coming to the question, I saw a youtube video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Ruc5rkDg1E) about transparent Jtextfield, but the same code isn't giving the same output.

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;

    public class TextField3 {
       public TextField3() {
          ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("pic1.jpg");
          //JLabel l1 = new JLabel();
          //l1.setBounds(0, 0, 900, 500);
          //l1.setIcon(icon);

          Color back = new Color(0, 0, 0, 80);
          Color fore = new Color(255, 255, 255);
          Font font = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 24);

          JFrame f1 = new JFrame("My First TextField");
          f1.setBounds(150, 50, 900, 500);
          //f1.setVisible(true);
          f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          f1.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

          JLabel l1 = new JLabel();
          l1.setBounds(0, 0, 900, 500);
          l1.setIcon(icon);

          JTextField tf = new JTextField("TextField");
          //tf.setOpaque(false);
          tf.setBounds(275, 150, 350, 60);
          tf.setVisible(true);
          tf.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

          tf.setBackground(back);
          tf.setForeground(fore);
          tf.setFont(font);

          f1.add(l1);
          f1.add(tf);
          f1.setVisible(true);
      }
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          TextField3 tf = new TextField3();
      }
    }
```

[The output from the youtube video.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6K8c.jpg)

[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5M29.png)

The code above isn't exactly same as the video's code. Actually the code in the video generated a blank JFrame, then I moved the JLabel portion of the code below the JFrame's part, then it produced the output in the 2nd image.

I searched about this issue and found that setOpaque to false will solve this. But when I tried it, the JTextField disappears completely and only the background image is shown. Can someone help in solving this issue?

Comment: but the thing is, textfield and the text are also not shown when I add setOpaque(false)

Comment: The structure of your code is completely wrong. You are not following Swing design principles. I have explained the problems in my answer in more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. You should NOT be using a null layout and you should NOT be using setBounds().

Swing is designed on a parent/child relationship. If you want the text field to appear on top of the label then don't add both components to the frame. Instead you need a structure like:

```
- frame
    - background label
        - text field
```

So your basic code should be something like:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField("text");
textField.setBackground(...);

JLabel background = new JLabel(...);
label.setlayout( new GridBagLayout() );
label.add(textField, new GridBagConstraints());

frame.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Now you will see the text field in the center of the label.

However, you will still have a problem with the semi-transparent background of the text field, since Swing does not handle semi-transparency properly. For more information and a solution check out: [Why does the alpha in this timer draw on top of itself in this Java Swing Panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63362910/why-does-the-alpha-in-this-timer-draw-on-top-of-itself-in-this-java-swing-panel/63364379#63364379)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I understand it now. Can you please link some resources to learn swing properly?

Comment: @MayankGoyal, glad it helped. Start with the [Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). It covers many of the Swing basics and each section has demo code to download and test.

Comment: Why are you using a JLabel as a container? You probably meant to use a JPanel.

Comment: @weisj, no, I meant to use a JLabel. This is an easy way to display an image at its actual size and have components displayed on top without doing any custom painting. Check out [Background Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) for the limitations of this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `setOpaque(false)` method to make your JTextField transparent. That should work.

Comment: I have tried it as you can see in the code, it's commented out. When I add that line, the JTextField disappears completely, and only the background image is shown.